# Is there a way to add raw html as new table rows with javascript?

Tags: javascript, html, html-table, yui

Let's say I have the following table:

```
<table>
  <tr id="1">...</tr>
  <tr id="2">..</tr>
  ...
  <tr id="last">..</tr>
</table>
```

I also have a third-party service from which I get some **raw html**, also table rows like this:

```
<tr id="additional-1">...</tr>
<tr id="additional2">...</tr>
```

Is there a relatively simple javascript way to insert those new rows after the tr with the id "last"?

I'm asking for simple built-in ways to avoid having to do a lot of parsing, replacing and stuff.

I prefer YUI 3 to jQuery solution.

Comment: was *just* about to post a jQuery solution when i read the last line. Let me know if you still would like it.

Comment: @ericosg yeah, I'm fine with jQuery, I just said that I "prefer" YUI :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Wrap the string in `<table><tbody>..rows here...</tbody></table>`. Then, create a dummy element, eg `<div>`, and set the `innerHTML` property to the previously constructed string. Finally, loop through all rows, and move the rows to the table using `insertBefore(newelem, reference)`.
This method also works in IE, where setting the `innerHTML` property on a cell triggers an error.

```
var raw_html, prev_element, last_element_parent, rows, i;
raw_html = '<tr>....etc....</tr>';
prev_element = document.getElementById('last_element');
last_element_parent = prev_element.parentNode;

dummy = document.createElement('div');
dummy.innerHTML = '<table><tbody>' + raw_html + '</tbody></table>';
rows = dummy.firstChild.rows;

for (i=rows.length-1; i>=0; i--) {
    last_element_parent.insertBefore(rows[i], prev_element.nextSibling);
}
```

Comment: I ended up using your solution. Only, for future readers, you could probably add a correction on the loop increment. What happens is that when you move the first element, the rows[] array gets smaller by one so it will only work for half the nodes.

Comment: @zladuric Amended: I've reversed the order of insertion. That eliminates the step of saving the "current" element in a temporary variable.

Answer (score 2):

What's about `table.innerHTML += trs` with `var table` stores the table-Object and `var trs` stores the additional rows.

Comment: Does not work in older versions of IE: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ie/ms533897(v=vs.85).aspx, "The innerHTML property is read-only on the col, colGroup, frameSet, html, head, style, table, tBody, tFoot, tHead, title, and tr objects.".

Comment: Maybe it doesn't work with old IE, but I don't need that support anyway. I think this will do it.

Comment: @zladuric IE8 is included in "old IE". There is still [a significant number of IE8 users](http://gs.statcounter.com/#browser_version-ww-monthly-201106-201206), so you do not want to use a method which doesn't work in IE8.

Comment: Yeah, I know, I don't need IE8 support. But that is not the problem. The problem is that my table is a bit more complex, with rowspans and colspans so I need to ask even more specific question.

Answer (score 1):

Following code should work

```
$("tr #last").after("ur raw html");
```

its Jquery though.

Answer (score 1):

In YUI3 you can do:

```
Y.one('#last').insert(rawHTML, 'after');
```